# How to clear local ssh port for forwarding to remote?

Tags: ssh, port

I'm using ssh forwarding local port to a bastion server(10.20.30.40), connect to remote RDS database.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -f -N -L 5432:db1.cluster-1.region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 10.20.30.40 -v
...
Authenticated to 10.20.30.40 ([10.20.30.40]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5432 forwarded to remote address db1.cluster-1.region.amazonaws.com:5432
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5432.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5432.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

The 5432 on local port will be used. If create a new forwarding

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -f -N -L 5433:db1.cluster-1.region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 10.20.30.40 -v
```

The 5433 port will be used.

If start 5432 in a new terminal, it will be failed because already in use.

```
Authenticated to 10.20.30.40 ([10.20.30.40]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5432 forwarded to remote address db1.cluster-1.region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5432.
bind [::1]:5432: Address already in use
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5432.
bind [127.0.0.1]:5432: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5432
Could not request local forwarding.
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

How to release these ports connection?

Comment: Close the previous connection.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider How to close the connection? Can it list all the ssh connection items?

Comment: list the running processes with `ps` and `kill` the process.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thank you! If you can write it down as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port is going to be blocked as long as your SSH session is active. If you weren't spawning it into the background with the `-f` parameter you could just log out or hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, you can't do that with the session in the background.

You can list running processes with `ps`. Then you kan `kill` the process.

```
$ ps  -af |grep ssh
username    2113    1822  0 10:19 pts/0    00:00:00 ssh -L 5433:db1.cluster-1.region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 host
$ kill 2113
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in-comments... that port is bound to the process that launched it. It will stay open until that process exits.

You can use the `-p` argument to `netstat` to see what processes are holding which ports open. I'd *highly* suggest you limit that to only TCP ports with the `-t` flag, as well... and finally, turn off DNS lookups with the `-n` flag.

So, you're looking at something like:

```
netstat -npt
```

That should "list" all ports currently in the state table, along with the process ID or program name. That last part will likely require privilege escalation through something like `sudo` (or Cygwin "Run as Administrator")

For example:

```
$ sudo netstat -npt
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8651          127.0.0.1:50644         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8649          127.0.0.1:53761         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58488         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0    348 172.16.XXX.YYY:22       172.16.XXX.ZZZ:54272    ESTABLISHED 21020/sshd: russell
...
```

Comment: Note that you can also add `-l` for "listening ports only."